# The easy API to get a longitude and latitude from a given city name

Tags: jquery, json, api, google-api, latitude-longitude

I want my vistior to enter a city name then I can  get the latitude and longitude from that name. I could not figure out how to get them using  google map api. I found world weather online api easy, so I have this json response but cannot walk through it.

```
{ "search_api" : {
    "result" : [
      { "areaName"   : [ { "value" : "New York" } ], 
        "country"    : [ { "value" : "United States Of America" } ],
        "latitude"   : "40.710",
        "longitude"  : "-74.010", 
        "population" : "8107916",  
        "region"     : [ { "value" : "New York" } ], 
        "weatherUrl" : [ { "value": "http:\/\/free.worldweatheronline.com\/weather\/United-States-Of-America\/2395340\/New-York\/2478232\/info.aspx" } ]
      }, 
      { "areaName"   : [ { "value" : "New York" } ],
        "country"    : [ { "value" : "United States Of America" } ],
        "latitude"   : "32.170",
        "longitude"  : "-95.670",
        "population" : "0",
        "region"     : [ { "value" : "Texas" } ],
        "weatherUrl" : [ { "value": "http:\/\/free.worldweatheronline.com\/weather\/United-States-Of-America\/2395340\/New-York\/2516758\/info.aspx" } ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This is what I tried:

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
  var cord = data.search_api.latitude;

  alert(cord);
} );
```

Can anybody help me out with this or give me a better way to get longitude and latitude from a given city name or address?

Comment: Don't the pre tags invalidate your json?

Comment: That looks okay. What does `console.log(data);` show in the browser's console?

Comment: pre tag is not part of my code, i thought it was going to organize my code :),

Comment: Pekka, it is showing me "Unexpected token :"

Comment: Lots of API's will return JSON but is it JSONP? If not you can't access it with javascript due to cross domain policies

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't work because you try to jump straight from `search_api` to `latitude` when you need to go through the array named `result` first, e.g.

```
$.getJSON( url, function( data ) {
  var firstResult = data.search_api.result[ 0 ];

  console.log( "City:",      firstResult.areaName[ 0 ].value, ",",
                             firstResult.region[ 0 ].value
  );
  console.log( "Latitude:",  firstResult.latitude );
  console.log( "Longitude:", firstResult.longitude );
} );

/* Output:
   > City: New York , New York
   > Latitude: 40.710
   > Longitude: -74.010
*/
```

Comment: That's too bad, but "didn't work" doesn't mean anything to us. What error did you get or what result did you get that you didn't expect? What is the value of `data`?

Comment: I want to show  the Latitude and  Longitude as you did here, but it gives me this "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :"

Comment: Debug it like you would any syntax error. What line in the code does it refer to? There's no syntax error in the code I posted so it's either in the JSON data (are you sure it's plain JSON?) or somewhere else in your code.